# SQL IP Address To Country Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, ip-address

I have a database filled with IP Addresses and want to add another column with the Two Letter Iso Region Name of the country each IP maps to. Hostip makes it pretty easy to get the country for each IP, but I'm not sure how to read what the following URL returns in SQL.

http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip={{some IP}}

Comment: It's a simple string? You will need to write a script to call the url for each of your ip addresses and use the result to update the record accordingly. You do not say which version of SQL server you are using, it's possible to the update from within SQL so see this link for pointers. http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=111356

Comment: Are you familiar with any scripting languages or SSIS?

Comment: I insert records into the database through C#, so I guess I'll just use a script there to add that column in. I was just wondering if there was an easy way to do it in SQL Server alone.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a web service in SQL Server. Not the thing that a database was designed for but it can be done: See [the tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428200/How-to-invoke-a-Web-Service-from-a-Stored-Procedur) by Omar Frometa. Instruction for SQL Server starts at step 5.

However, I think you are much better off with extract the IP Addresses in a programming language, call the webservice, then return the country code back to SQL Server.

Comment: I insert records into the database through C#, so I guess I'll just use a script there to add that column in. I was just wondering if there was an easy way to do it in SQL Server alone.

Comment: SQL Server is the hard way to do it. It's a database language, not a general programming language. You will be better off calling the webservice in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using the `sp_OACreate` procedures to call a web service from within a stored procedure:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428200/How-to-invoke-a-Web-Service-from-a-Stored-Procedur

`sp_OACreate` is not necessarily the most stable or supported way of doing things, so this is really just an illustration, not a recommendation.

If you want to pursue this option, you create the stored procedure and call your web service then update your table with the result of the stored procedure.

However if the IP addresses are being inserted from your C# program then you should probably do it from there instead.